# Audio Source Signal Separation of 'Cocktail Party'

Tags: python, ruby, audio, signal-processing

I am looking for a code snippet that I have seen demonstrated as an inspiration to students that will process 2 audio files, recorded with 2 microphones that are spaced apart recording a 'cocktail' party, which will produce 2 or more separate outputs to isolate different voices on the basis of differential delay.

The example I have seen used a single formula in python script to produce this effect, any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry it's an off-site resource, so not a good question for SO. This is a now famous solution, the Matlab code is a one-liner: `[W,s,v] = svd((repmat(sum(x.*x,1),size(x,1),1).*x)*x');` - that might help your search (I don't have any other references, that code was from notes on a Coursera Machine Learning course).

Answer (score 1):

(It might be suitable as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do that yet.)

This is not a Python code, but if you are looking for a example sound file, you can get that from following link.

http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/cocktail/cocktail_en.cgi

PS: About the comment from Neil Slater, to run the Matlab code, we need Octave package installed.

Answer (score 0):

from numpy import *

U, S, Vh = linalg.svd(dot((tile(sum(x*x,0),(x.shape[0],1))*x),x.T))